# Negative bias in sample auto-correlation of uncorrelated time-series

Tags: autocorrelation

I am using the following definition for the **sample auto-correlation**:

$AC_x(l)=∑_{i=1}^{N-l}(x_i-μ)(x_{i+l}-μ)$    ;    $μ=\frac{1}{N}∑_{i=1}^Nx_i$

I have noticed that this definition introduce a systematic negative bias to the results due to the subtraction of the sample mean. I calculated the auto-correlation of a white noise sample and after repeating that for thousands of realizations and averaging them in each time lag, I got that bias (attached are my code).

I was really surprise at first, but then, I calculated $E(AC_x(l))$ ($E$ for expectancy value) by hand and got: $E(AC_x(l))=-(1-\frac{l}{N})E(x_i^2)$ $^1$ (for $l>0$). This is the exact pattern I got in my simulations.

**So, my question is how should I interpret that? And which definition I should use for auto-correlation in order to get the intuitive result of $\delta(l)$?**

```
def autocorrelation(x):
    x_mean = np.mean(x)
    x_var = np.sum((x-x_mean)**2)
    corrs = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        test_x1 = x[:(len(x)-i)]
        test_x2 = x[i:]
        corrs.append(np.sum((test_x1 - x_mean) * (test_x2 - x_mean)) / x_var)
    return np.array(corrs)
```

```
s = np.random.normal(size=(10000, 10))
corrs = np.array([autocorrelation(s[i]) for i in range(s.shape[0])])
```

```
plt.figure(figsize=(4*3, 3*3))
plt.errorbar(np.arange(1, corrs.shape[1]), np.mean(corrs[:, 1:], axis=0), st.sem(corrs[:, 1:], axis=0))
plt.xlabel('time lag')
plt.ylabel('correlation')
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(1, corrs.shape[1]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

$^1$ A full proof of the bias expression:

\begin{align}
E(AC_l (x))&=E(\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}(x_i-μ)(x_{i+l}-μ))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}E((x_i-μ)(x_{i+l}-μ))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}E(x_i x_{i+l}-x_i μ-x_{i+l} μ+μ^2 )\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}E(x_i x_{i+l} )-E(x_i μ)-E(x_{i+l} μ)+E(μ^2 )\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}E(x_i x_{i+l})\\
&\phantom{=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}}-E\left(x_i\frac {x_1+⋯+x_N }{N}\right)\\
&\phantom{=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}}-E\left(x_{i+l}\frac {x_1+⋯+x_N }{N}\right)\\
&\phantom{=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}}+E\left(\left(\frac {x_1+⋯+x_N }{N}\right)^2\right)\tag{a}
\end{align}

Now, for $i\ne j$: $E(x_i x_j )=E(x_i )E(x_j )=0$, because they are independent and each with 0 mean, therefore a lot of mixed elements will fall off, and we will stay with:

\begin{align}
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}\left(-E(\frac{x_i^2}{N})-E(\frac{x_{i+l}^2}{N})+E(\frac{x_1^2+⋯+x_N^2}{N^2})\right)\tag{b}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}\left(-\frac{E(x_i^2 )}{N}-\frac{E(x_{i+l}^2)}{N}+\frac{E(x_1^2)+⋯+E(x_N^2)}{N^2}\right)\tag{c}
\end{align}

$x_i$ are identically distributed, therefore:

\begin{align}
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}\frac{-NE(x_i^2 )-NE(x_i^2 )+NE(x_i^2 )}{N^2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-l}-\frac{E(x_i^2 )}{N}\tag{*}\\
&=-\frac{N-l}{N} E(x_i^2) \\
&=-(1-\frac{l}{N})E(x_i^2)
\end{align}

And this is exactly what the simulation shows for N=10

Comment: if your noise **is** white, then $\mu\equiv 0$. Otherwise, the noise wasn't white. Attention, you'd need an infinitely large $N$ to really measure that, though the error gets smaller proportionally to $N$.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks a lot for your response. 1. I was asking on the interpretation of the auto-correlation of a finite sample of some random process (white noise, for example). At first, I was expecting to get a delta function, but actually I got a non-zero bias (that can be mathematically expressed, as I showed). 2. This negative bias does not get smaller as N get larger, it's actually increases (in absolute term) and converges to -1. I would be very glad to hear your interpretation for finite sample auto-correlation, or another valid way to calculate it.

Comment: :) I'd like to, but really, the expectation of the autocorrelation of a white series is 0, per definition of "white" for any non-zero lag $l$ (there, it's its Variance). Could you maybe add the calculation that led to your expectation value to your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I attached the mathematical "proof" above in the main text cause it was too long for comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: beautified your equations a bit :) Let me have a look at it, might take a few minutes, though.

Comment: hm, latest in your $(*)$ line, there's something wrong; that's always a negative value.

Comment: ah! $(a)$ to $(b)$ doesn't hold for *finite* sums; $(\alpha+\beta+\ldots+\omega)^2\ne\alpha^2 +\beta^2+\ldots+\omega^2$.

Comment: 1. In $(*)$ it is indeed always negative, you can see it also in the simulation. I don't find any algebraic mistake there. 2. $(a)$ -> $(b)$ doesn't hold in the general case, but because $x_i$ are independent so $E(x_i x_j)=E(x_i)E(x_j)=0$, therefore, all the mixed elements fall off. I am quite sure that I don't have an algebraic mistake cause the bias accurately comes up also in an independent simulation (as I showed). There is something wrong with the basic definition and its interpretation. @MarcusMüller, thanks again for your help!

Comment: I feel kind of stupid here, you're right.

Comment: @Tomer Milo: As you showed, the "intuitive" formula results in bias. This document explains it pretty clearly. Thanks for interesting question. https://www.ece.mcmaster.ca/~ibruce/courses/COE4TL4_lecture29.pdf. Note that it doesn't matter in this case but statisticians use a normalization factor  when calculating the autocorrelation. DSP people call autocorrelation what statisticians call autocovariance. But that's not important here.

Comment: @Tomer Milo: looked at this a little more careully and you actual proved the result that there is negative bias in the case where the underlying data is independent so that the true underlying  correlation equal zero at all lags.  But even in the dependent case, the "standard" acf formula is biased. This link kind of shows the general case but I'm still looking for a detailed proof. Your proof was nice but it used independence. The general case doesn't assume independence.  https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/4.pdf. If I find something good, I'll send link.

Comment: I found what looks like a nice proof on crossvalidated. I haven't gone through it but atleast someone knows where to go if they want to look at it.  In the not uncorrelated case, you still lose observations at lags less than the lag that you want to calculate the acf at so that's where the bias term in the barlett link comes from.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278703/how-to-estimate-the-autocorrelation-function

Comment: @markleeds, Thanks a lot for your comments and for the links. I will look at those...

Comment: Tomer Milo: I still have't found a good proof. Your proof was interesting but it's using independence when the usual use of an acf is when there is dependence. So, the links that I sent consider the case where there is dependence in the data and the usual acf estimator is still biased ( and with a similar term for the bias as yours except opposite sign ).  This bias is because of the loss of the terms in the sum due to the fact that 2L observations are lost when one calculates the autocorrelation at lag L. Still, your proof was neat and thought provoking. Thanks.